# Error in forming dictionary from a csv file in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a csv file whose structure is like this:

```
Year-Sem,Course,Studentid,Score
201001,CS301,100,363
201001,CS301,101,283
201001,CS301,102,332
201001,CS301,103,254
201002,CS302,101,466
201002,CS302,102,500
```

Here each year is divided into two semesters - 01 (for fall) and 02 (for spring) and data has years from 2008 till 2014 (for a total of 14 semesters). Now what I want to do is to form a dictionary where `course` and `studentid` become the key and there respective `score` ordered by the `year-sem` as values. So the output should be something like this for each student:

```
[(studentid,course):(year-sem1 score,year-sem2 score,...)]
```

I first tried to make a dictionary of `[(studentid,course):(score)]` using this code but I get error as `IndexError: list index out of range`:

```
with open('file1.csv', mode='rU') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile,dialect=csv.excel_tab)
        with open('file2.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            mydict = {(rows[2],rows[1]): rows[3] for rows in reader}
            writer.writerows(mydict)
```

When I was not using `dialect=csv.excel_tab` and `rU` then I was getting error as `_csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?`.

How can I resolve this error and form the dictionary with structure `[(studentid,course):(year-sem1 score,year-sem2 score,...)]` that I had mentioned in my post above?

Comment: what output do you want?

Comment: I want the output in `[(studentid,course):(year-sem1 score,year-sem2 score,...)]`

Comment: so basically in the order it appears?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham keys can be in any order but the values in each keys should be in increasing order of year-sem

Comment: If the data is ordered then the values should be ordered, add the output you expect from your input example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialect you've chosen seems to be wrong. `csv.excel_tab` uses the tabulator character as delimiter. For your data, the default dialect should work.

You got the error message about newlines earlier because of the missing `U` in the `rU` mode.

```py
with open(r"test.csv", "rU") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

This example seems to work for me (Python 3).

Comment: and how do I form the values part of the dictionary ordered by year-sem for each key? right now I am forming dictionary of structure `[(studentid,course):(score)]` but I want it to be of `[(studentid,course):(year-sem1 score,year-sem2 score,...)]`?

Comment: You could make your dictionary a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) where every entry is a list: `mydict = defaultdict(list)` and then you can just append to it: `mydict[(studentid, course)].append(year-x score)`.

Comment: I tried `mydict = {(rows[1],rows[2]): rows[3] for rows in reader};writer.writerows(mydict)` but in my output file I see only values for keys(row[1] and row[2]) and not the values(row[3])

Answer (score 0):

If you have repeating keys you need to store the values in some container, if you want the data ordered you will need to use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
import csv
from collections import OrderedDict

with open("in.csv") as infile, open('file2.csv', mode='w') as outfile:
    d = OrderedDict()
    reader,  writer = csv.reader(infile), csv.writer(outfile)
    header = next(reader) # skip header
    # choose whatever column names you want
    writer.writerow(["id-crse","score"])
     # unpack the values from each row
    for yr, cre, stid, scr in reader:
        # use id and course as keys and append scores
        d.setdefault("{} {}".format(stid, cre),[]).append(scr)
    # iterate over the dict keys and values and write each new row
    for k,v in d.items():
        writer.writerow([k] + v)
```

Which will give you something like:

```
id-crse,score
100 CS301,363
101 CS301,283
102 CS301,332
103 CS301,254
101 CS302,466
102 CS302,500
```

In your own code you would only store the last value for the key, you also only write the keys using `writer.writerows(mydict)` as you are just iterating over the keys of the dict, not the keys and values. If the data is not all in chronological order you will have to call sorted on the reader object using itemgetter:

```
for yr, cre, stid, scr in sorted(reader,key=operator.itemgetter(3)):
   ............
```